# Loading file from resource gives a wrong path

Tags: java, jar

I have a propeties file with a path to a file inside my jar

```
logo.cgp=images/cgp-logo.jpg
```

This file already exists:

[image]

I want to load this file within my project so I do this:

```
String property = p.getProperty("logo.cgp"); //This returns "images/cgp-logo.jpg"
File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(property).getFile());
```

But then when I do `file.exists()` I get `false`. When I check `file.getAbsolutePath()` it leads to `C:\\images\\cgp-logo.jpg`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well a file inside a jar is simply **not** a regular file. It is a resource that can be loaded by a ClassLoader and read as a stream but not a file.

According to the Javadocs, `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(property)` returns an `URL` and `getFile()` on an URL says :

> Gets the file name of this URL. The returned file portion will be the same as getPath(), plus the concatenation of the value of getQuery(), if any. If there is no query portion, this method and getPath() will return identical results.

So for a jar resource it is the same as `getPath()` that returns :

> the path part of this URL, or an empty string if one does not exist

So here you get back `/images/cgp-logo.jpg` *relative to the classpath*  **that does not correspond to a real file on your file system**.  That also explains the return value of `file.getAbsolutePath()`

The correct way to get access to a resource is:

```
InputStream istream =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(property)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class like this:

```
JarFile jar = new JarFile("foo.jar");
String file = "file.txt";
JarEntry entry = jar.getEntry(file);
InputStream input = jar.getInputStream(entry);
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
    for (int i = 0; i != -1; i = input.read(buffer)) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, i);
    }
} finally {
    jar.close();
    input.close();
    output.close();
}
```